# pass struct and its member field(s) as mutable references to a function

Tags: rust

How to avoid passing mutable reference of a struct and mutable reference of its field(s) to a function. I know I'm violating the the rule "only one mutable reference or any number of immutable references in a scope".

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Shared {
    data: HashMap<i32, i32>,
    inv_data: HashMap<i32, i32>,
    // so many other fields are present
}

fn foo(d: &mut i32, sh: &mut Shared) {
    // sh.inv_data and also other fields of struct Shared will be accessed here
}

fn main() {
    let mutex_data = Mutex::new(Shared::default());
    {
        let sh = &mut mutex_data.lock().unwrap();
        sh.data.insert(1, 1);
        sh.data.insert(2, 2);
        sh.data.insert(3, 3);
        sh.data.insert(4, 4);
        sh.data.insert(5, 5);
    }
    
    {
        let sh = &mut mutex_data.lock().unwrap();
        let data = sh.data.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
        foo(data, sh);
    }
}
```

Error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*sh` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:28:19
   |
27 |         let data = sh.data.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
   |                    -- first mutable borrow occurs here
28 |         foo(data, sh);
   |         ---       ^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |
   |         first borrow later used by call
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. As you said, the compiler will prevent you from doing this for safety reasons. Instead, you should change the signature of `foo` since you already have a mutable reference to your `Shared` instance.

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Shared {
    data: HashMap<i32, i32>,
    inv_data: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

fn foo(sh: &mut Shared) {
    let data = sh.data.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mutex_data = Mutex::new(Shared::default());
    {
        let sh = &mut mutex_data.lock().unwrap();
        sh.data.insert(1, 1);
        sh.data.insert(2, 2);
        sh.data.insert(3, 3);
        sh.data.insert(4, 4);
        sh.data.insert(5, 5);
    }
    
    {
        let sh = &mut mutex_data.lock().unwrap();
        foo(sh);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the function signature. Imagine the situation wherein I need to iterate over `Shared::data` hashmap and for each pair element(key, val) I need to call `foo`.

Comment: What do you need a mutable reference to `Shared` in `foo` for?

Comment: I will be updating the other fields of `Shared` doing some computations

Comment: To me, it looks like `Shared` is an attempt to a self-referential data structure (judging by the presence of both `data` and `inv_data` fields), and the signature of `foo` is also a reflection of this. In this case, the compiler is telling you that your abstraction is not idiomatic. I would insist on changing the signature of foo if you want to minimize the amount of changes that your code requires, but as I was saying, I think this is case of an XY problem. For example, foo could take an `i32` rather than a `&mut i32`, so that you know on which key from the HashMap to perform the mutation on.

Comment: @Harry Do you also need to update the maps that you're iterating over? If yes, the compiler just saved you from a great mistake. If not, split the `Shared` struct into two (or more) pieces.